# Pass a json output as argument to a linux program in java

Tags: java, json, linux

I'm trying to pass a string variable to a linux process that takes for input json files. I need however to use the redirect "<" for the program to be able to read the input as a string, otherwise it reads it as a filename.

**Correct behavior: /usr/bin/program < "json content"**

The use of the redirect sign "<" in java is being taken for an argument, which is not what i'm looking to do here.

Is there any other way to use the redirect sign correctly in java?

Comment: Redirection is done on the shell level, so basically in your java application you need to read stdin (that is [System.in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in))

Comment: Oops, it seems that I misunderstood your question. Do you invoke an external process from Java which should receive data from stdin?

Comment: @user3159253 I'm invoking an external process in Java which should receive data from a variable inside my class.

Answer (score 0):

The `<` character isn't interpreted by the Linux kernel, it's interpreted by your shell. What you're doing is the same as if you wrote `/usr/bin/program \< "json content"` in a shell -- note the escaped backslash.

To replicate the shell's behavior with Java code, you should do something along the lines of this (but with more error handling):

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/program").start();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new InputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("json content\n");
writer.close(); // flush stream and send EOF
```

Comment: I've tried this with OutputStreamWriter instead of InputStreamWriter, and the process is not taking any arguments, it's as if i executed the linux program without any arguments. I suppose it's a question of timing(between the execution of the process and the writing in its inputstream)